# ASP Razor page and Netescapades CORS/CSP Error with statcounter

Tags: asp.net-core, cors, razor-pages, content-security-policy

I have added a bunch of CSP/CORS config using the security header from netescapade for wr4vr.org and for some reason I can't get this counter to work. Any Suggestions?

Also the twitter feed but it has no errors and that is a later issue unless someone know that fix. Because it works if I remove all the CSP/CORS config from the pipeline.

http://wr4vr.org

[image]

```
var policyCollection = new HeaderPolicyCollection()
       .AddFrameOptionsDeny()
       .AddXssProtectionBlock()
       .AddContentTypeOptionsNoSniff()
       .AddStrictTransportSecurityMaxAgeIncludeSubDomains(maxAgeInSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 365) // maxage = one year in seconds
       .AddReferrerPolicyStrictOriginWhenCrossOrigin()
       .RemoveServerHeader()
    
       .AddPermissionsPolicy(builder =>
       {
           builder.AddCustomFeature("iframe")
               .Self()
               .For("https://platform.twitter.com");
       })
       .AddContentSecurityPolicy(builder =>
       {
           builder.AddObjectSrc().None();
           builder.AddFormAction().Self();
           builder.AddFrameAncestors().None();
           builder.AddUpgradeInsecureRequests();
           
           builder.AddDefaultSrc()
               .Self()
               .WithNonce().From("http:").From("https:")
               .From("cdn.jsdelivr.net");

           builder.AddScriptSrc() // script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'nonce-<base64-value>'
                .Self().From("www.statcounter.com")
                .From("www.google-analytics.com")
                .From("cdn.jsdelivr.net")
                .WithNonce(); // Allow elements marked with a nonce attribute

           builder.AddFrameSrc().Self()
                .From("platform.twitter.com")
                .From("www.statcounter.com")
           .From("www.google-analytics.com").WithNonce();

           builder.AddConnectSrc()
                .Self().From("ws:").From("wss:").From("https:").From("http:");
           

           builder.AddStyleSrc() // style-src 'self' 'strict-dynamic' 'sha256-<base64-value>'
               .Self().UnsafeInline()
               .From("platform.twitter.com")
               .From("cdn.jsdelivr.net")
               .From("www.statcounter.com")
               .WithHashTagHelper(); // Allow whitelsited elements based on their SHA256 hash value
       

       })
       .AddCrossOriginOpenerPolicy(builder =>
       {
           builder.SameOrigin();
       })
       .AddCrossOriginEmbedderPolicy(builder =>
       {
           builder.RequireCorp();
       })
       .AddCrossOriginResourcePolicy(builder =>
       {
           builder.SameOrigin();
       });



app.UseSecurityHeaders(policyCollection);
```

And the CORS code

```
var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.WithOrigins("www.statcounter.com",
                                              "www.google-analytics.com",
                                              "platform.twitter.com");
                           
                      });
});
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
```

Comment: Have you configured Cors in your project? refer to this [Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Yep but probably screwed that up

Comment: Can't reproduce your project, But from the error message, the problem caused by Cors, you need to debug your project according to this link i provided.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using this implementation in `program.cs` in ASP.NET Core

```
builder.Services.AddCors(policy =>
{
    policy.AddPolicy("NewPolicy", opt => opt
   .AllowAnyOrigin()
   .AllowAnyHeader()
   .AllowAnyMethod());
});
```

And lastly

```
app.UseCors("NewPolicy");
```